# What's the difference between a 'development stack' and a 'framework'?

Tags: php, laravel

**Head coder:**
You should now be ready to install Laravel Homestead.

**Me:**
oh awesome. I've always wanted to learn Laravel framework.

**Head coder:**
We are not going to use the laravel framework, but we do take advantage of their development stack.

What does this mean?

Comment: A framework is a set of functions that help you code because you can call them to accomplish your task. A development stack is a series of  technologies(which might use frameworks) usually in a level heirarchy that call each other to accomplish all the tasks an application might need. eg. LAMP -> Linux Apache MySQL PHP stack vs CodeIgniter or Laravel i.e. PHP frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A framework is a set of functions that help you code because you can call them to accomplish your task. A development stack is a series of technologies(which might use frameworks) usually in a level heirarchy that call each other to accomplish all the tasks an application might need.

### E.G.

#### LAMP -> Linux Apache MySQL PHP stack

Note all 4 of these are technologies. Starting from the OS linux, the web server Apache, the database server MySQL and the server side programming language PHP

[image]

### CodeIgniter or Laravel i.e. PHP frameworks

Frameworks are extensions of languages that are really good at doing certain things. For example both CodeIgniter and Laravel are good for programming web servers and make it easier to do so in PHP.

Another example of a framework could be the bootstrap framework which allows you to do HTML easier or jQuery.

### Now, to Laravel and Homestead

The Laravel Homestead is a relatively new concept. Laravel is PHP based and previously you had to set up your own LAMP or WAMP(Windows) stack to work with it. Now, what they have done is set up a custom stack, tailored for Laravel and PHP development.

They've used Vagrant, which is used to help you test your code on a virtual Machine, essentially installing an entire stack ready for development on a platter. With Laravel's VM (Homestead) you get a bunch of stuff ready including MySQL and PostGRE (databases), Redis and Memcached (Caching), Nginx (a web server like Apache) etc.

So now you have something nice to program Laravel on right out of the box. But, you need not necessarily use Laravel. Its also ideal for building any PHP app or using other PHP frameworks like Codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand by dev stack is the set of technologies you use for your project, while the framework provides solutions for a specific set of problems, say building CRUD web apps,  at the cost of following its guidelines, most of the time ***becoming*** your project.

Following that statement, the stack may be: "Laravel, node, gulp, mysql, composer, etc"

While the framework is without a doubt Laravel itself, which attempts to solve problems pertaining to **CRUD MVC** web apps.

---

I think your head programmer meant you will be using the built in PHP, Apache, MySql and perhaps composer. Maybe the point is that you can all work in an environment that holds the same known configurations and tools (since its conveniently configured for PHP development).